# Do I misunderstand the "can't be reproduced" close-reason?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I did just fail my first close-review (I did just get two in a row, but that wasn't the real issue here...), and I'd like to get some feedback on how I should have decided.

[The question I got](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/6157696) has a long error log, followed by the statement that the OP has no idea where that error comes from.

Ok, not the best question, but it is a framework tag, so it might me useful to others.

The, there are two comments, one stating that packages differ from the expected, and another stating that this was caused by an error during server upgrade. Both comments are up-voted twice.

Here I supposed that the problem is a niche problem that happened once, caused by a server upgrade that failed - and we have a close reason for that.
*But apparently I shouldn't have done it...*

Was I wrong, or is this another head of the review hydra of bad reviews?

Comment: I wouldn't say that it can't be reproduced if others are likely to run into the same issue.

Comment: I too agree with the failed audit; it's obvious from the comments that this is a reproducible error, and shouldn't be closed as such.

Comment: @cybermonkey Reading the answers, it seems to be an error in the framework...

Comment: @Theolodis then it's definitely not no-repro. At least until the framework gets fixed (at which point - or sooner - the question should be edited)

Comment: @JanDvorak it seems to be fixed already... at least that's stated at one mailing list linked in an answer.

Comment: That second comment explicitly states it can't be reproduced, but isn't by the OP and the commentator's answer has a workaround, strongly suggesting they *were* able to reproduce it. Seems like a perfectly valid question.

Comment: @ssube yeah, I supposed that it could be reproduced, but it is **no longer** reproducable... am i wrong?

Comment: A question where somebody posts a bunch of Java code, for example, that has an issue, complete with detailed analysis, troubleshooting steps, prior research, theories, etc., but then discovers their problem is that, say, they simply forgot to save some changed files in Eclipse before running the program -- this is a good example of "no longer reproducable".

Comment: @JasonC thanks, that makes sense... I did somehow interpret "no longer" as "was, but isn't anymore"...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your definition of "no longer reproducible" applies to almost every question that is answered on SO. "Problem solved?" - "Okay, close the question!" That can't be right. :)

"No longer reproducible" means that the behaviour cannot be reproduced. Sometimes the problem is gone already and OP is still looking for the unknown cause of this problem that has disappeared into oblivion. Usually these attempts are in vain, and for SO people to help with this is even more fruitless. Since the problem itself is gone, you cannot debug the code, so all you can do is just stare at the code and hope you find an anomaly that might have caused a problem in some very specific circumstance.

In some cases, the other party (us answerers) cannot reproduce the problem. That might be because we have a different platform or because OP isn't able to isolate the problem enough to make a good question. In those cases, I think 'too broad' or 'unclear' or 'why isn't this code working' are better close reasons.

If it is an issue that is known to be solved by updating some piece of software, then there is a clear problem, which is reproducible (probably by building a system that has the wrong version of the package), and which is likely to be an issue for other people as well.

So in this case it's not an issue that disappeared automagically, but a real problem with a real solution that might be useful to others too. There is no reason to close this question, or more precisely, *this* is not the right reason to close this question. ;)